# Plots don't change with changing dates in shiny dashborad in r

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I have made a dashboard using shinydashboard in r where user can select the date range and variable to be plotted. The prolem is that when I change the date range, the plot doesn't change. Though it changes when I change the variable.

Sample data(which I read from csv file):

```
Date        Total_Orders   Delivered_orders   Cancelled_orders   NEW_USERS_COUNT 
2015-04-30     23             12               2                  21
2015-05-01     43             21               12                 32
2015-05-02     32             13               10                 30
2015-05-03     43             32               7                  14
2015-05-04     43             22               3                  21
2015-05-05     32             21               1                  22
```

Code that I have used:

ui.R

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")
dashboardPage(

dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),

dashboardSidebar(img(src="jpeg.jpg", length = 75, width = 230),
               dateRangeInput("daterange", "Select Date range:",
                              start = "2014-06-01",
                              end = "2015-06-30"),
               selectInput("var", "Choose a variable to display",
                           choices = c('Total_Orders' = 'Total_Orders', 
                                       'Delivered_orders' = 'Delivered_orders', 
                                       'Cancelled_orders' = 'Cancelled_orders', 
                                       'NEW_USERS_COUNT' = 'NEW_USERS_COUNT'),
                           selected = "Total_Orders")

               ),
dashboardBody(

fluidRow(
  box(title = "plot", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, 
      collapsible = TRUE, plotOutput("chart1", height = 250, width = 500)) 
  )
  )
)
```

server.R

```
library("shiny")
library("data.table")
file <-     read.csv('filepath.csv', header = TRUE)
setnames(file, old = c('X_id'), new = c('date'))
file$date <- as.Date(strptime(file$date, "%Y-%m-%d" ))

shinyServer(function(input, output)

{output$chart1 <- renderPlot({

               start_date <- input$daterange[1]
               end_date <- input$daterange[2]

               subset(file, date >= start_date & date   <= start_date)

               point <- switch(input$var,
               'Total_Orders' = file$Total_Orders, 
               'Cancelled_orders' = file$Cancelled_orders,
               'Delivered_orders' = file$Delivered_ordes,
               'NEW_USERS_COUNT' = file$NEW_USERS_COUNT
               )
               plot(file$date, point, type = "b")
 }) 
})
```

Can anyone suggest if I am doing something wrong or missing out anything?

Answer (score 1):

try forcing the strings from the ui to be dates in the subset

`subset(file, date >= as.Date(start_date) & date   <= as.Date(start_date))`